# Modularizing service provider node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, adonis.js

So I have a Service provider that I want to break down in modules but can’t wrap my head around a solution, is there a correct way of doing this?

```
const module= use('module')

class Class{
  constructor (Config) {
    this.Config = Config
    this.module= module
  }

  async login() {
    try {
      this.module.login()
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }

  async logout() {
    try {
      await this.module.logout()
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }

  async foo(){
    try {

        await this.login()

        const account = this.module.createAccount()

        await this.logout()

        return account
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
```

I would like to have multiple modules : auth.js and accounts.js, etc… that I could access from my class without losing the instance of module, because I can’t call my methods without doing the login() part.

like so:

```
const module = use('module')
const AccountModule= use('./account-module.js')
const AuthModule= use('./auth-module.js')

class Class{
  constructor (Config) {
    this.Config = Config
    this.auth = AuthModule(module)
    this.accountModule = AccountModule(module, this.auth)
  }

  async bar() {
    try {
      const account = await this.accountModule.foo()
      return account
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }

}
```

`auth-module.js`

```
export default module => ({
  async login() {
    try {
      module.login()
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  },

  async logout() {
    try {
      await module.logout()
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
})
```

`account-module.js`

```
export default (module,auth) => ({
  async foo(){
    try {

        await auth.login()

        const account = module.createAccount()

        await auth.logout()

        return account
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: Correct me if I wrong. You want access to the Class instance, in both account-module.js and auth-module.js. Right?

Comment: Not necessarily the Class instance, I need to access the `module` instance in the Class instance, the module sets a auth_token on login method that I require for account modules methods, like the module.createAccount() method.